# How to parse and cache nested JSON objects with GSON?

Tags: android, gson

I am implementing an Android RESTful client API. I would like to use GSON to parse all of the incoming JSON responses into my java models, then use Sugar ORM to cache all of the data to the database for offline viewing.

I have an "Author" model and a "Book" model. Ideally, you should be able to parse and cache an Author by doing this:

```
Author author = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, Author.class);
author.save();  // Saves the record to the db
```

However, my JSON structure is much more complex, and it isn't something that I can change. Also, this does not separate the Book objects. For example, here is the JSON response that will populate a ListView of Authors. Embedded with the Author is an array of Books.

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://myapi.com/authors"
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "authors": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "website": "http://johndoe.com",
        "email": "john.doe@myapi.com",
        "bio": "Est rem et dolores illo est. Non quaerat aut. Id doloribus sed dicta     exercitationem et. Perferendis aut necessitatibus debitis.\nEt earum est. Voluptatem minima     suscipit blanditiis. Porro fugiat aliquam quia. Eum error et quibusdam dolores est architecto et.",
        "likes_count": 4,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://myapi.com/authors/1"
          }
        },
        "_embedded": {
          "group": null,
          "books": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Book 1",
              "_links": {
                "self": {
                  "href": "http://myapi.com/books/1"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "website": "http://janedoe.com",
        "email": "jane.doe@myapi.com",
        "bio": "Excepturi dolorem laboriosam odio et quis itaque laudantium. Neque perspiciatis facere harum eligendi nemo veritatis ut. Qui occaecati facilis voluptatem ut consectetur placeat dolor. Veritatis quasi iste veniam aut. Expedita qui voluptate aut molestiae fuga quas itaque.\nVeritatis perspiciatis officiis quis dicta. Omnis voluptas possimus. Ut non rerum atque molestiae et consequatur aut. Quo molestiae animi aut nam voluptatem iusto.",
        "likes_count": 10,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://myapi.com/authors/2"
          }
        },
        "_embedded": {
          "group": null,
          "books": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "A Book By Jane Doe",
              "_links": {
                "self": {
                  "href": "http://myapi.com/books/2"
                }
                }
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Another Book by Jane Doe",
                "_links": {
                "self": {
                  "href": "http://myapi.com/books/3"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my Author model:

```
public class Author extends SugarRecord<Author> {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private long authorId;
    private String name;
    private String website;
    private String email;
    private String bio;
    @SerializedName("likes_count")
    private int likesCount;
    private String href;

    ...
}
```

And here is my Book model:

```
public class Book extends SugarRecord<Book> {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private long bookId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String publisher;
    private int yearPublished;
    private String rating;
    @SerializedName("likes_count")
    private int likesCount;
    private String href;

    ...
}
```

For now, I am just iterating through the JSONArray of authors, and using the code above to parse and cache each Author (except for the "href"). My question is, how do I use GSON to parse out the Books into their own model (not part of the Author model). Is this even possible with GSON?

Thank you for your help and let me know if I need to make something more clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible to parse complexe json structure with gson, you can implement `JsonDeserializer<T>` and parse your json as you like, if you have a very big json response it might get you some memory problems in this case it's better to use `TypeAdapter<T>` here is a great tutorial i hope it will help you [gson-deserialiser-example](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)